# Using a list of Json results as parameters for a mvc actionresult, to return objects from database with Linq and Lambda

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda, json.net

There is an `Api` method called via `Ajax`. After parsing and other necessary things has been finished, I get the following result.

```
["IG4","E1 ","E16"]
```

As soon as the results received, it calls another `MVC ActionResult` to display data from the database, where the postcode attribute of the object contains one of these `Json` results. However it does not work.

```
public ActionResult SearchResult(JsonResult postcode)
    {
        var posts = db.Posts.Where(p => p.PostCode.Contains(postcode));
        return PartialView("postlist", posts);

    }
```

When the `ActionResult` is called via `Ajax`, I checked what `url` is being called and got the following result

```
SearchResult?postcode%5B%5D=IG4&postcode%5B%5D=E1+&postcode%5B%5D=E16


$('#searchBtn').on('click', function () {
        var _postcode = $('#searchPostcode').val();
        var _distance = $('#searchDistance').val();
        alert("postcode " + _postcode + " distance " + _distance);
        var _url = '@Url.Action("GetPostcodesWithin", "Api/PostcodeApi")';  // don't hard code url's
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: _url,
            data: { postcode: _postcode, distance: _distance },
            success: function(data) {                    
                alert("search ok");

                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: '@Url.Action("SearchResult", "Posts")',
                    data: { postcode: data },
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert("Post results called");
                        $("#postList").html(data).show();
                    },
                    error: function (reponse) {
                        alert("error : " + reponse);
                    }
                });
            },
            error: function (reponse) {
                alert("error : " + reponse);
            }
        });
    });
```

`Json` data returned from `GetPostcodesWithin` method is displayed on the top, which is passed onto `SearchResult`

Comment: Instead of JsonResult, try using string[], that might pick up all the values.  However, it does not look like your ajax post is posting an array.  Can you show the javascript as well?

Comment: are you return data in list ?

Comment: Yes, list of string

Comment: *it does not work* Please be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to change the method to

```
public ActionResult SearchResult(IEnumerable<string> postcode)
```

Then change the 2nd ajax call to

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '@Url.Action("SearchResult", "Posts")',
    data: { postcode: data },
    traditional: true, // add this
    success: function (data) {
        ....
    }
})
```

The parameter `postcode` in the `SearchResult()` method will then contain the 3 string values from your array.

Because you now have a collection of strings, your query now needs to be

```
var posts = db.Posts.Where(p => postcode.Contains(p.PostCode));
```

Side note: Your second value contains a space (`"EF "`) which may need to be trimmed?

Comment: Thank you Stephen. I do see what difference it made after adding the line `traditional: true`. However I still can not get the `Linq` command right in the SearchResult `ActionMethod` to look for Posts in the database, containing any of a list of strings, instead of just a string. `Contains()` method does not seem to take a `List<string>` as an argument. Is there any way around this? I could separate the list in `Ajax` and with `foreach` (if there are 3 items in list), it would call the `ActionMethod` three times. I do not think that is the best way of doing it

Comment: I got the following error `Cannot create an instance of an interface. ` Also `intellisense` said `IEnumarable<string>` does not contain the method `Contains()`, so I had to change it to `IQueryable<char>` in order to rebuild the project and still got that error.

Comment: Oops - had a typo - that should have been `.Contains(p.PostCode)));` - see update

Comment: Have just edited again to show a simpler implementation

Comment: Now it shows no errors when I use `IEnumerable<string>` as argument, but still does not work. I get the following error message `DbExpressionBinding requires an input expression with a collection ResultType.
Parameter name: input`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116283/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-sugafree).